# Fancybox not working with images from Twitter API

Tags: javascript, twitter, fancybox, fancybox-2

With Fancybox 2 the example below works flawlessly (left out other code)

```
<a class="fancybox" href="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2169856486/avatar.jpg" title="some title">
        <img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2169856486/avatar_normal.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

but the code below load the image on a separate page

```
<a class="fancybox" href="https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=boris&size=original" title="some title">
        <img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2169856486/avatar_normal.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

The problem seem to be with the image URL the Twitter API supplies which returns a (301) redirect to the actual location of the full image. Is there any way i can get Fancybox to work with images that are supplied using a redirect and that the popup window still has the size of the served image.

Help would be appreciated.

Frank

Comment: How about opening the twitter API url in an iFrame rather than an image?

Comment: Hi Jacob, this is something i also thought of but the window wouldn't resize to the correct w/h of the image which is different for each image.

Comment: Have a go and then try this for the resize http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389927/fancybox-updating-size-of-fancybox-with-iframe-content

Answer (score 13):

Since the second code/link doesn't contain an image extension (jpg, gif, png), fancybox cannot determine what `type` of content is trying to open so you need to tell it.

Either do :

**One**: Add the `type` option to your custom script

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   type: "image"
 });
```

**Two** : add the `data-fancybox-type` attribute to your link

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="image" href="https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=boris&size=original" title="some title"><img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2169856486/avatar_normal.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```