# FancyBox doesn't work with url without extension

Tags: java, jquery, image, spring-mvc, fancybox

I have following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }
      }); 

});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a class="image" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg"  title="Singapore from the air (Andrew Tan 2011)">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg" alt="" />
```

it works as expected when click on image:

[image]

if rewrite body like this:

```
<a class="image" href="http://localhost:9091/member/createCompany/getOriginalImage/1"  title="Singapore from the air (Andrew Tan 2011)">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg" alt="" />
```

I see following result when I click on picture:

[image]

I don't understand what the problem. please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected if add .jpg at the end of the url.

```
href="http://localhost:9091/member/createCompany/getOriginalImage/1.jpg"
```

But I don't know why.

I've found related links:

[Fancybox urls without .jpg opens not in box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547727/fancybox-urls-without-jpg-opens-not-in-box)
[Fancybox not working with images from Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476701/fancybox-not-working-with-images-from-twitter-api)