# change fancybox size

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I show an iframe with fancybox. Inside the HTML of the iframe I do this:

```
<body style="width: 650px; height: 430px;">
```

Then in JS I do the followig:

```
$(".popup").fancybox({
    padding : 0,
    closeBtn : false,
    autoSize  : true,
    fitToView : false,    
    beforeShow: function()
    {
        this.width = ($("iframe").contents().find("body").width());
        this.height = ($("iframe").contents().find("body").height());
    }
});
```

Where ".popup" is:

```
<a href="url.php" class="popup" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
```

If inside that iframe I load another HTML with different dimensions (let's say 400x150), fancybox adjust it's height but not it's width.

any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT 1**:

The first time I run fancy box, the ".fancybox-inner" div get styled like this

```
width: 650px; height: 430px;
```

Then, when I navigate inside the iframe, the ".fancybox-inner" div get styled like this

```
width: 650px; height: 150px;
```

but the second HTML body tag is like this

```
<body style="width: 400px; height: 150px;">
```

**EDIT 2:**

the comments from this [solution](http://www.ianhoar.com/2011/08/25/jquery-and-fancybox-how-to-automatically-set-the-height-of-an-iframe-lightbox/) linked in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221369/702353), indicates me that this only works with the height

Comment: Have you checked if      ($("iframe").contents().find("body").width()); gives a proper value?

Comment: @thaJeztah I console.log that and it only fires once at the first load.

Comment: so the problem seems not to be that you're unable to set the dimensions (which works the first time), but that beforeShow() is only triggered once. You might edit/update your question to clarify this. Also, I found this, which seems similar, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769151/fancy-box-work-with-iframes-in-beforeshow-function

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes! that's where I've got de beforeShow code. The thing is that if I navigate inside the iframe and the next page has different dimensions, the fancybox somehow only adjusts it's height

Comment: Have you tried disabling autoSize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I ended up doing this using fancybox version: 2.1.4 (Thu, 10 Jan 2013)

at line 1231 you will find

```
origHeight = body.height();
```

After that add this

```
origWidth = body.width();
```

That auto adjust both height and with

Comment: Be sure and check this off as the answer for future viewers.

Comment: @Grinn: Next time I will debug 2000 lines of someone else code before posting. Come on! If it adjust in height, one will expect that it will also adjust in width

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying - for the sake of Stack Overflow viewers who may be experiencing the same issue, you should mark your answer as being correct.

Comment: @Grinn: Oh I'm sorry! I thought that your were reproving me for posting my answer before checking the plugin code. I read it the worng way. Please accept my sincere apologies! I didn't mark it as correct before because I have to wait a day to mark my own response

Comment: No problem. I figured that was the case.