# How to set fancybox height and width identical?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I need to set the height and width 1:1 and I wrote a function like this:

```
function fancyboxSize () {
    $('.fancybox-skin').css({'min-height':$(this).width()});
    $('.fancybox-inner').css({'min-height':$(this).width()});
}
```

And called it out like so:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  afterLoad : function(){
   fancyboxSize();
  }
});
```

but this doesn't work, it just makes it really high, how could I set it to be a perfect box? Version I'm using is `2.1.4`

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590426/change-fancybox-size

Comment: You set `min-height`, the real height can be really higher. It's how min-height works. Can you please create a fiddle to see the real example?

Comment: Add some screen shots so we can understand problem.